# Android MvvmCross bind Text to MvxCommand

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an Android Application and use Xamarin and MvvmCross. I have a EditText and would like to call a command everytime the text changes.

The command in the VM:

```
    public MvxCommand<string> SearchContactsCommand => new MvxCommand<string>(SearchContacts);

    private void SearchContacts(string searchTerm)
    {
        // Do search
    }
```

And this is the Edit box:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxLang="Hint SearchPlaceholder"
            local:MvxBind="TextChanged SearchContactsCommand" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I tried it with different variations of TextChanged without success.

If possible I would like to avoid having a property on the VM for the searchterm and execute the search in the setter of it.

Is there any way how I can achieve that or do I have to write a custom binding?

Version:
- MvvmCross 5.6.3
- MvvmCross.Binding 5.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no built in binding that can do that, you'll have to do a custom one. [Here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L80) you can see almost all of the built bindings there are. The others are in Droid support plugins in the Mvx{NameOfTheDroidSupportPart}SetupHelper.cs files like `MvxPreferenceSetupHelper.cs` inside `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Preference` if you want to see them too.

I'm not sure what you are aiming with that but if you want to do an autocomplete you can use `MvxAutoCompleteTextView`. [Here](https://github.com/JimWilcox3/MvxAutoCompleteTest) you have an example. And also look into [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/b8b860e63f7dfd445231308cf20ced0d56ae6e75/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat/Target/MvxAppCompatAutoCompleteTextViewPartialTextTargetBinding.cs) that is the binding the autocomplete uses to fire the change every time the value changes you just have to adapt it to trigger a command with the value as the parameter.

Any problem just ask and I'll be glad to help